# What is the difference between these two Postgres query

Tags: postgresql-9.1

```
Select sum(a),sum(b) 
from table 
where c like '234%' 
  and time > '2013-12-31' 
  and d = 'hello';
```

Then I explicitly calculate the value of `sum(a)-sum(b)`.

```
Select sum(a-b) 
from table 
where c like '234%' 
  and time > '2013-12-31' 
  and d = 'hello';
```

As both of these queries are giving different results.

By Doing an EXPLAIN ANALYSE on both of these queries, I see that second query has removed more rows by Filter conditions.

I am not able to find an explanation for this.

Comment: Why don't you show us the execution plans. Ideally uploaded to http://explain.depesz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is likely due to nulls existing within the data. If you had "a" as 3 and "b" as null then you'd receive a null result on something like:

```
select 3 - null;
```

Doing the sums individually will allow each to increment to the actual sums skipping nulls only for that individual column not the entire row and likely be more of what you're looking for.